# When does List.addAll() throw IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, list, addition, illegalargumentexception

I have code

```
private List<Field> subFields;
private Collection<Field> subFieldsCollection;

...

try {
    if (subFields == null && subFieldsCollection != null && !subFieldsCollection.isEmpty()) {
        subFields = new ArrayList<>();
        subFields.addAll(subFieldsCollection);
    }
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    ...
}
```

and I'm wondering how can it happen for `IllegalStateException` to be thrown. It apparently happened to a user of my app, but I'm not able to track what was wrong.

The documentation of `Collection.addAll()` says:

> IllegalArgumentException - **if not all the elements can be added at this time due to insertion restrictions**

But what are the insertion restrictions?

I guess it depends on the exact type of the collection. I'm using ArrayList, so let's check docs for `addAll()` of `List` interface:

> IllegalArgumentException - **if some property of an element of the specified collection prevents it from being added to this list**

Well, what element property could prevent  the element to be added to the List? My both Collections are of the same type, I should be able to add null values..

Can anybody explain this to me, please?

Comment: I'm just shooting in the dark here, but might it not be connected to concurrency?

Comment: It's not entirely clear which version of Java you're using but the source code for Java SE 6 never throws that exception from `addAll()` except indirectly when accessing the `Collection`. Have you seen the stack trace and are you sure where the exception is thrown?

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: @VGR @DanAllen I'm using Java SE 7 and unfortunately don't have access to the stack trace. I found this piece of code in an app I'm working on, encapsulated in try catch block for `IllegalStateException` and was wandering how could that happen.

Comment: Unless the subFields.addAll line is the only line in that try-block, how can you be sure addAll is what caused the exception, without seeing the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much information you have from the user, this may be unanswerable. But I'll make a guess, and delete my answer if further evidence comes to light that contravenes it. :)

Assuming you wrote all the code, I agree that `addAll()` cannot throw `IllegalStateException` (and all the talk about `IllegalArgumentException` is irrelevant).

My guess is that the error does not originate from the `addAll()` call but from another call in the code (not shown) that attempts to manipulate one of these collections. It *is* possible to get an `IllegalStateException` by attempting to, for example, iterate through the list (using an iterator obtained with `.iterator()`) and remove an item, then attempt to remove another item without calling `Iterator.next()`. Similarly, `Iterator.set()` can throw one in an iterator obtained from an `ArrayList`. So my guess is, somewhere in manipulating the list, one of these things happens.

Alternatively, there are many ways that *other* collection implementations could throw one. So if we're not sure it pertained to the `ArrayList`, then we've got very little to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can never throw IllegalArgumentException because [ArrayList#addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) cannot throw such exception.

In order to get that exception you have to use a class implementing Collection where such exception can be thrown. You could easily make your own by extending ArrayList and overriding involved methods.

Comment: A future implementation of `ArrayList#addAll` **could** throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (i.e. next version of jre). But of course this is pretty unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any implementations (in the jre or any library) that throw an IllegalArgumentException.

But you could easily create your own implementation, that throws such an exception. The interface `Collection` makes the users aware, that an implementor **could** use an `IllegalArgumentException` - it does not say, that the implementors *actualy do* use it.

An example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PickyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public static class SpecialThing {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        if (e instanceof SpecialThing)
            return super.add(e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

}
```

As a result I would recommend this approach:

- check your code, that you are adding **semantically reasonable** items to your collection. Do not add objects of class `Person` to a list called `postalCodes`
- handle any technical runtime exception in **an appropriate way**. For example rollback transactions, do logging, inform the user and/or the support team
- consider to **inform callers of your method** (via JavaDoc), that your method could fail

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the implementation. If you check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) for `ArrayList`, which is the actual class your using, you'll see this.

> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the specified collection is null

So your `ArrayList` should not throw the `IllegalArgumentException`. If you would use another implementation or a wrapper (see [unmodifiable list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29), **note** that this example does not throw such an exception), it might throw such an exception.

So get the logging from your user and try to reproduce the issue.